# What is the required ground size for the S2LP RF module?

Tags: rf, antenna, module

I'm designing a four layer board with an [RC-S2LP-868-HA](https://www.radiocontrolli.com/en/component/124/rc-s2lp-868-ha) RF module which has a little helical antenna.

I have two question about that.

First, how do I calculate the required ground size for the RF module? It will operating 868MHz.

I have designed a 90 mm x 40 mm sized PCB, the GND size is 80 mm x 40 mm. I'm not sure that will good.

My second question is, that do I need ground islands on top and bottom side? Or this will cause some don't wanted effects?

[image: The PCB]

Comment: Have you actually read the data sheet? If so, then what was it that you found unclear?

Comment: Of course I read the data sheet, but there is no information about these.

Comment: So, next, have you spoken with the company that supplies them?